# EPSON LQ 300+ Paper Feed incorrectly in VB.Net 2005

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005, epson, dot-matrix

In my Billing Form, i am using raw data to print in the rollpaper with EPSON LQ300+.

I set defaulty 3inches paper feed in Printer for the purpose of manually cutting the Bill.

And i call the FF(12) printer command after a bill print. It's working fine.

But some cases the paper feeding increases upto 5inches. I don't why?

I need excat 3inches for all Bill.

Comment: Is there anything different about those cases where it feeds 5 inches instead of 3 inches?

Comment: yes bill length may differs but i watch some similar cases also have the same problem